# Trouble displaying images in a MAUI ListView from a local .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, maui

I'm currently in the process of tinkering a little with the MAUI framework for .NET. I'm running into an issue i can't seem to solve.

I want to show a Listview of locations with a name and image associated with them. But can't seem to get MAUI to show my image. I'm serving it through a .NET API where the file is stored locally and served though a controller GET endpoint.

The relevant parts of my code

Note: ImageUrl is hardcoded for testing purposes. Would be provided alongside my model in real-world application

Controller method to serve image

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("{imageId}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(PhysicalFileResult))]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage(Guid imageId)
        {
            string imagePath = await _imageLogic.GetImagePathAsync(imageId);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imagePath))
                return NoContent();

            try
            {
                return PhysicalFile(imagePath, "image/png");
            }
            catch
            {
                return NoContent();
            }
        }
```

XAML view

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:LocationModel">
                    <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}"
                               ImageSource="https://127.0.0.1:44361/api/image/77f71959-2447-4551-fdbf-08db55730dab"
                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

When I use a random image url from Google, it all works as expected. Not sure where the error is, as if I use the link directly in browser og Postman, I see the image fine, with a httpcode 200.

I've tried to alter the API method with return type FileResult and PhysicalFileResult. Tried in MAUI to create a ImageSource from the URI, to no avail.

Comment: do NOT use `localhost`.  Use the IP or FQDN of your server.  And test the url in the browser of the **device/emulator**, not your desktop.  Also note that by default the built in VS web server does not allow requests from remote machines, and your device/emulator is most likely considered remote.

Comment: @Jason it should be noted that i use 127.0.0.1 ip from the Android emulator. It was a brainfart that localhost is in the question, I'll update it. In addition I have fine access to other api methods from the device

Comment: `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` tells Android to **connect to itself**, not the server.  There are numerous posts and articles about how to configure the Android emulator to talk to a server running on the host PC

Comment: Shouldn't that keep me from using the api overall? I have access to the api fine, and through debugging can see that the method is hit.

Comment: this is usually the root issues in 99% of the cases when trying to use a local server.  If you're certain that the request is making it to your server, then you need to keep debugging.  The VS output log may have helpful information.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 should not be hitting it. On top of everything - https.